# EpiServer - easy way to mock UrlResolver

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

Is there an easy way to mock UrlResolver class?
I pass it as a parameter to the constructor.

```
public Service(UrlResolver urlResolver){
    _urlResolver = urlResolver;
}
```

**EDIT:**
According to Henrik N. comment, this issue had been addressed in EpiServer 8.

But until I have an EpiServer 8 in my solution I will use custom interface + adapter.

Comment: Note that the problem with mocking UrlResolver was addressed in EPiServer.CMS.Core 8.0.0 by changing the class to be an abstract base class without any dependencies.

Comment: If so, then this question is obsolete. Please add an answer and I will mark it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependency that is causing the issue was removed in version 8.0.0 of EPiServer.CMS.Core so if you can update to the latest version you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up creating my own IUrlResolver interface and adapter for UrlResolver.

```cs
public interface IUrlResolver
{
    string GetUrl(ContentReference contentReference, Language language);
}

public class UrlResolverAdapter : IUrlResolver
{
    public string GetUrl(ContentReference contentReference, Language language)
    {
        return UrlResolver.Current.GetUrl(contentReference, language);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go for most (if not all) of EPiServers tightly coupled mess...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Using the excellent [FakeItEasy](http://fakeiteasy.github.io/) mocking library, it's as easy as:

```cs
UrlResolver fakeUrlResolver = A.Fake<UrlResolver>();
```

Then use it to instantiate your `Service`.

```cs
var myService = new Service(fakeUrlResolver);
```

If you need the fake to return on specific method calls, that's possible too. Say, the code fetches the public URL for a `PageReference`.

```cs
PageReference myLink = new PageReference(123);
UrlResolver fakeUrlResolver = A.Fake<UrlResolver>();
A.CallTo(() => fakeUrlResolver.GetUrl(myLink)).Returns("my/fake/url");

// probably initialize some other code with myLink at this point

var myService = new Service(fakeUrlResolver);
```

Comment: Did you tested this code? I'vetried to use Rhino Mocks to Mock it but it throws exception, because the default constructor for UrlResolver , resolve couple of dependencies from ServiceLocator and it cause trouble.

Comment: I wrote this answer based on code that works. What does Rhino Mocks have to do with this?

Comment: Oh, I read the other comments. I obviously have tested this only on some versions.